# Projections in semi-normed spaces

Tags: normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, projection, positive-semidefinite, bilinear-form

I have a question regarding the projection onto a finite-dimensional subspace of a semi-normed vector space:

Let $V$ be a real vector space (either finite or infinite-dimensional) and let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V \to \mathbf{R}$ be a symmetric positive semi-definite bilinearform. Denote the corresponding semi-norm by $\|\cdot\|=\sqrt{\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle}$ and let further $U\subseteq V$ be a finite-dimensional subspace of $V$.

**Question:** Under which conditions is the projection $P_U:V\to V, v\mapsto argmin_{u\in U} \|v-u\|$ well-defined in the sense that the argmin exists and is unique?

If I am not mistaken, then it suffices that the restriction of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to $U$ is an inner product. Or do I need completeness or definiteness of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $V$ for $P_U$ to be well-defined?

**Edit:** Here is my approach: Let $\{u_1,\dots,u_d\}$ be a basis of $U$. Let $v\in V$ be fixed. Then for any $u=\sum_{j=1}^d u_j\beta_j$ it holds:

\begin{align*} \|v-u\|^2&=\|v\|^2-2\langle v,u\rangle + \|u\|^2
\\&=\|v\|^2-2\sum_{j=1}^d \beta_j \langle u_j,v\rangle+\sum_{j,k=1}^d \beta_j\beta_k \langle u_j,u_k\rangle\\&=:\|v\|^2-2\beta^T \gamma(v) + \beta^T G\beta.
\end{align*}

Differentiating with respect to $\beta$ and equating with $0$ shows that the coefficients of the minimizer must satisfy the equations $G\beta=\gamma(v)$. If the restriction of  $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ to $U$ is an inner product, then $G$ is positive definite and the unique minimizer has coefficients $G^{-1}\gamma(v)$.

Comment: Definiteness is needed for the uniqueness, and completeness is needed for the existence.

Comment: @AnneBauval Hi, thanks for your quick reply! I added my approach where I neither use completeness nor definiteness on V (only on U). Do you think that is correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your question carefully. First, I missed your assumption that U
 is finite-dimensional. It implies completeness of U
, which is sufficient for the existence (even when U
 is infinite dimensional). Second, I missed that your question was whether we need stronger assumptions (on V
). I believe that your fine proof that we don't (for the uniqueness) generalizes to the case where the Hilbert space U
 is infinite dimensional.

Comment: Okay, many thanks! Do you by any chance know a good reference for this? I mainly find references where V is assumed to be Hilbert space.

Comment: When $U$ is a Hilbert space, for the existence I only have [this page of the French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_projection_sur_un_convexe_ferm%C3%A9) (and its own references), and for the uniqueness, you will easily adapt your proof by taking a [Hilbert basis](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_de_Hilbert) of $U.$